# Trying to get a specific layout in HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my scenario:

I have a fixed-positioned DIV element (lets call it 'wrap'). It must not overflow the margins of 100px from the window's edges.

Inside this div reside 3 other DIVs ('first', 'second', and 'third').

Only the 'third' DIV has a fixed height and should always be positioned at the bottom of the containing 'wrap' DIV.

The issue is that I want the 'wrap' DIV to occupy as less possible height of the screen. I want it to shrink its height if 'first' and 'second' are fully shown, and scroll 'second' if they don't.

I find it kind of hard to explain, so I hope you can get the idea.
Ask me anything if you need any clarifications.

I've created a pen for it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nirarazi/pen/ecbKJ) that you can fork and play with.

I can't succeed in achieving this without JS.

I'll really appreciate your help...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom styles for varying screen sizes using [@media](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/) in your style sheet like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 0;
  }
  #column-main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #column-sidebar {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Visit [here](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries) for a better explanation.

Comment: and within the media queries, perhaps adjust the width of your elements, for example set your list items to be 100% in width, this way they stretch across the entire window. Within your media queries, you may need to reference a parent selector to modify the current selector, i.e #wrapper ul {... }

Comment: @Antarr: thanks a lot for answering.
I'm aware of media queries. The problem is not with the varying widths. 'second' DIV contains forms that have different heights, and I want it to affect the height of 'wrap' and still never flow outside of the bottom margin.

Comment: @nir.arazi For your wrap you have bottom set to auto have you ride using `bottom: 5px;}`, or what ever size margin you want?

Comment: @AntarrByrd: Yes. I started out with `bottom:0` and `margin:100px` and tried `bottom:100px` as well. This way the wrap size is always maximum, and that's not good for me either. I want it ('wrap') to be as high as it needs (dictated by its children) but never exceed the margin.